# How to interpret geometrically this space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Good Evening. I'm trying to do this exercise, but I have many doubts. Let be $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $W=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x+y+z=0\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find the quotient vector space $\mathbb{R}^3/W$

My work:

I need to find the equivalence class of $'u'$ a generic or vector belonging to the quotient. So I thought $u=(a,b,c),v=(d,e,f)$ both in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then $uRv$ iff $u-v\in W$ So I cleared the variable $x$ of $W$ and write the plane as $W=\{(-y-z,y,z):y,z\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and I got it $[u]=\{(y+z+a,b-y,c-z):y,z\in \mathbb{R}\}$, where $[u]$ represents the equivalence class of $u$, then $\mathbb{R}^3/W=\{[u]:u\in \mathbb{R}^3\}$ I do not understand the partition that generates this set on $\mathbb{R}^3$, I do not know what geometrical interpretation also provides. How I find the equivalence class vector (1,2,3)? Help me please...Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your plane $W = \{(x, y, z): x + y + z = 0\}$ in green and vector $v = (1, 2, 3)$ in blue.

[image]

Now we add the plane $W' = \{(x, y, z): x + y + z = 10\}$ in dark blue (shown as a triangular grid so you can see through it).

[image]

And a secondary shot, so you can see the two really are parallel, with the terminal point of $v$ lying on $W'$.

[image]

Now we'll add some vectors $v_i'$ whose terminal points are also on $W'$, in red. Note that $v - v_i' \in W$, and are thus in the equivalence class $[(1, 2, 3)]$, since the terminal points of both are in $W'$. They really do differ by a vector in $W$, and we can see: the line segment joining them is in the plane $W'$, with $W'$ parallel to $W$.

[image]

And, for good measure, another perspective.

[image]

What do other equivalence classes look like? All the vectors whose terminal points are in some plane parallel to $W$, with these planes having varying distance from $W$. Here are several of these planes, in various colors (with the original plane in green still):

[image]

In fact, for each distance $d \in \Bbb R$, there is a unique plane $W_d$ parallel to $W$ that is distance $d$ from $W$: it is the plane $W_d = \{(x, y, z): x + y + z = \frac{d}{\sqrt{3}}\}$. The set of all vectors whose terminal points lie in a plane $W_d$ constitute an equivalence class $[\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(d,d,d)]$ in $\Bbb R^3 / W$.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are awesome! =)

Comment: You are quite welcome! It was my computer that did all the hard work :)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but a similar exercise I'm doing in this case would be $W={(x,y,z)∈R3:2x−y+2z=0}$ the equivalence class of "u" would this $[u]={(x,y,z)∈R3:2x−y+2z=2a−2b+2c}$ when a,b,ca,b,c are the components of the vector u? I wanted to make sure I'm understanding, for example ${3,2,1]=${(x,y,z)∈R3:2x−y+2z=6}$?

Comment: @DanielaRondón I think you want the vectors in $[u]$ to satisfy $2x - y + 2z = 2a - b + 2c$ (just $-b$, not $-2b$). Otherwise, that looks good!

Comment: Yes, you are totally right! For example this vector quotient space  makes any sense $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @DanielaRondón The $\Bbb R^2 / \Bbb R$ that you've written doesn't *exactly* make sense, because there isn't just a single subspace $\Bbb R$ living in $\Bbb R^2$: There are lots and lots of them. So technically, you should write something like $\Bbb R^2 / \operatorname{Span}((1, 0))$ or something. But no matter which $1$-dimensional subspace $W$ isomorphic to $\Bbb R$ you choose, $\Bbb R^2 / W$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$. The broad strokes are the same, but the details do matter to some extent.

Comment: Then what has emerged me a doubt $\mathbb{R}$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is analogous subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$? yes or no, I confused ...

Answer (score 3):

$W = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x + y + z = 0 \}$ is a plane passing through $(0,0,0)$, normal to the vector $(1,1,1)$.

For $u = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$, geometrically $u + W$ is the plane $W$ translated by $u$. Equivalently, it is the plane normal to $(1,1,1)$, passing through the point $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$.

Algebraically,
$$
[u] = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x + y + z = u_1 + u_2 + u_3 \}.
$$

For $u = (1,2,3)$, this set of points is

$$
[(1,2,3)] = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x + y + z = 6\},
$$

which has the geometric interpretation as I explained above.

Comment: Thank you, but i don't understand still. How I find the equivalence class vector (1,2,3)? How do you know which is the plane normal to the point (1,1,1)? What I've done so far is correct?

Comment: Well $W$ is the plane passing through zero normal to $(1,1,1)$ since it is the set of points such that $(x,y,z)\cdot(1,1,1) = 0$. Then clearly from the meaning of $u + W$, you are just adding $u$ to the vectors in this plane, so you just get a translation. There are different ways to represent the equivalence class. I have given several options in my answer. Just plug in $(1,2,3).$

Comment: $[1,2,3]=\{(y+z+1,2-y,c-3)\}$?

Comment: What you have written does not really mean anything. I meant to plug in $(1,2,3)$ into the any of the representations I gave in my answer and interpret the geometric meaning as I explained already. It is just a shift of the plane $W$ by the vector $(1,2,3)$.

Comment: I plugged in the point in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much and really excuse me, I can not understand a bit this topic, can you please recommend any good book explaining why quotient vector space related to linear algebra?

Comment: I don't know of any linear algebra books that go into quotient spaces. I think you don't need to learn about quotient spaces so much as just understanding the geometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I recommend any of Gilbert Strang's books and his online lectures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40639/discussion-between-daniela-rondon-and-cat).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but a similar exercise I'm doing in this case would be $W=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:2x-y+2z=0\}$ the equivalence class of "u" would this $[u]=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:2x-y+2z=2a-2b+2c\}$ when $a,b,c$ are the components of the vector u?